# How can add anything from database to variable

Tags: php, sql, database

I have 2 tables and the first table of users, while the second table for profile imgs. And when someone wants to sign up I want to send users information **after** id on users table to profile img table. And when users information finish I need to take the user id from the users table after I need to send this information to profileimg table. (i using "userid" but not auto inc...) and when I try to send this code, I see "array" on profileimg userid. how can I do this?

I cant get information from the database

I am using MySQL.

```
else{
    $sql  = "INSERT INTO users (username, email, password, fname, sname, gender, birthday) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
    $stmt = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
    if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
        header("Location: ../kayitol.php?yanlis=sqlerror");
        exit();
    } else {
        $hashedPwd = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
        mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sssssss", $username, $email, $hashedPwd, $fname, $sname, $gender, $birthday);
        mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
        **  ** myproblemstartsfromhere **  ** *
        if (!mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql)) {
            header("Location: ../kayitol.php?yanlis=sqlerror");
            exit();
        } else {
            $sql    = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND fname='$fname'";
            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
            if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result));
                $userid = $row['idUsers'];
                $sql    = "INSERT INTO profileimg (userid, status) VALUES ('$userid', 1)";
                mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
                header("Location: ../kayitol.php?kayit=basarili");
                exit();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this line :

```
$userid = $row = ['idUsers'];
```

to:

```
$userid = $row['idUsers'];
```

Comment: oh thank you but now i cant see array, i see nothing. i write wrong "=", i saw now thank you. but my problem is i cant get any database information.

Comment: and i want to say. registration system using stmt codes but i didnt use this thing for profileimg table. and i dont know how can i write for stmt codes